# Difference between portal and non-portal web pages?

Tags: web-applications, portal

What is the difference between portal and non-portal web pages?

Answer (score 7):

A portal is a gateway page that provides a summary to lots of different (and only lightly related) things along with a way of getting the full version (links). Take for example, the [BBC](http://bbc.co.uk/), [Yahoo!](http://yahoo.com) and [MSN](http://msn.com/) homepages. A portal is designed to be set as your homepage and be the starting point for just about everything you do on the web.

A non-portal … doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

a portal page is defined by a mechanism to lay out portlets to form a page. portlets are a standard way of generating page fragments. you can think of portlets as servlets that suitable for generating a page fragment instead of an entire page.

exactly what mechanism the portal page uses for layout depends on the portal. unfortunately there is no standard for that. this probably doesn't answer your question very well, but it's almost impossible to answer without knowing that portal product / project that is used to generate the page. and that's at least one of the problems with portals.

Answer (score 0):

In some systems a "Portal" page refers to a page that is published through a content management system.

A "Non-Portal" page would then be a programmed rather than a published page.

Answer (score 0):

In think, in simple terms portal web page is aggregation of web page fragments coming from sources  where as non-portal page is mostly complete web page owned by single source.